# I can't connect to SQL Server 2014 Analysis Services

Tags: sql-server, ssas

I'm trying to connect to Analysis Services in SQL Server 2014 on server (local), but appears this error:

> Cannot connect to (local). Additional Information: A Connection cannot
>   be made. Ensure that the server is running.
>   (Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient) A connection cannot be made
>   because the destination computer had refused.

Please help me solving this.

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what to do (*Ensure that the server is running*). Have you done so?

Comment: @KenWhite yes, the server is running. Already tried to reinstall the SASS and nothing.

Comment: *the server is running*, do you mean that the SSAS service in the server is running?

Comment: I think it is. How can I check 100% if it's running?

Comment: "SQL Server>Configuration Tools>SQL Server Configuration Manager" and check if the service is up

Comment: @Lamak thank you for your fast reply. On the menu only appears this services: SQL Server Browser, SQL Server, SQL Server Agent. It should appear the SSAS, right?

Comment: Are you checking this in the server?, if so, then yes, it should appear SQL Server Analysis Service, otherwise it isn't installed

Comment: Can you give me a link where I can download the tool? Just to check If I downloaded the right one. And yes, I'm checking in the server.

Comment: you probably just didn't choose to install that service when installing SQL Server. Sorry, can't take the time to search for a link

Comment: @Lamak okok, no problem. I just think this is a bit weird because I have this paste on C: Microsoft Analysis Services

Comment: I think I got the solution. On this edition of SQL Server, it doens't support the Analysis Services, I need to install the Enterprise Edition.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Developer edition.

In my case, MS Analysis Services was not installed and that's why it was giving error. I ran the setup.exe to launch the installation wizard to add Analysis Services feature in my MS Sql Server and then it got resolved.

Since, I am using everything on one machine which is Windows Server 2012, I didn't require to make any change in firewall setting.